# Javascript not waiting on async Firebase Realtime Database Set function

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

although I thought I got the gist of how async functions work in JS, this one does not wait correctly.
Outer function, handling a social media like button press:

```
if (!postLiked){
        likePost (uid, cardData)
        .then (getPostLiked(uid))
        .catch (error => console.log (error))
    }
```

Now the likePost function, updating data on the firebase realtime database:

```
export function likePost(uid, cardData) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   //do stuff with the data...

    set(ref(db, `${cardData.path}/likeData`), {
        likeUids: newLikeUids,
        likeCount: newLikeCount
    })
    .then (() => resolve ("DB: Uid like entry modified"))
    .catch (error => reject (error))
  })
}
```

Expected behaviour: The post is first liked, then the like status of the post gets updated, indicating a successful like.
Shown behaviour: The getpostLiked function does not await the likePost execution, does not updating the like status.

Please help me find the mistake... in other instances, using the `then` expression after`set` has always worked well...

Many thanks!

Comment: The firebase set function changes a node's data on the FB realtime database: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is

```
likePost(uid, cardData)
  .then(getPostLiked(uid))
```

This is essentially equivalent to

```
const result = getPostLiked(uid);
likePost(uid, cardData)
  .then(result)
```

You're calling `getPostLiked` immediately instead of calling it only when the `likePost` promise resolves. Change it to

```
.then(() => getPostLiked(uid))
```

It'd also be a good idea to avoid the explicit Promise construction antipattern - since `set` already returns a Promise, there's no need to construct another one around it.

```
export function likePost(uid, cardData) {
  return set(ref(db, `${cardData.path}/likeData`), {
    likeUids: newLikeUids,
    likeCount: newLikeCount
  });
}
```

If the purpose of the Promise constructor was to change the resolve value, then do that with a `.then` after the `set` instead of wrapping in another Promise.

```
export function likePost(uid, cardData) {
  return set(ref(db, `${cardData.path}/likeData`), {
    likeUids: newLikeUids,
    likeCount: newLikeCount
  })
    .then(() => "DB: Uid like entry modified");
}
```